# MySql LIKE not working

Tags: php, mysql

LIKE not working when i searched for 'New Delhi' but when i Searched for Noida it works fine. how to use LIKE when String has Space.

```
$area = $_REQUEST('area');
$sql = "SELECT * from Student_registration WHERE area LIKE %".$area."%";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the single quotes to surround your string :

```
$sql = "SELECT * from Student_registration WHERE area LIKE '%".$area."%'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing quotes  around search condition

```
"SELECT * from Student_registration WHERE area LIKE '%". $area."%'";
```

or

```
"SELECT * from Student_registration WHERE area LIKE concat('%', '" .$area. ",'%'";
```